# Jquery mousedown/mouseup prevent click

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, mousedown, mouseup

My page is built like that:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                  Test
                  <div class="drag"/>
            </th>
            <th>
              ......
              ......
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

```css
.drag {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 3px;
}
```

The intention is to drag the width of the my colums with mousedown/mouseup-events on the `<div class="drag"/>` and it works nice. But there's also a click event on my `<th>`-elements.
The problem is, when I release the mouse still on the `<th>`, the click event still of `<th>` triggers.

I've tried several things:

- stopPropagation() on almost every event that's there
- return false in the mousedown event
- unbind the click event in mousedown and bind it again in the mouseup event

Is there any other way to prevent the click-event?

**Edit:**
I still want to keep the click-event on that `<th>` but I dont want it to start after i've dragged

Comment: Please add a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) from your code so we can see it working (even if it's with dummy actions). Right now, you don't show any script (and the question has only script tags), and the CSS doesn't match the posted HTML

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried

```
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

This will call stopPropagation, but also prevents other handlers within the same element from receiving the event.

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('th').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this stop the desired click event even when the user is not drag-n-dropping?

Comment: well, yeah. but he asked "Is there any other way to prevent the click-event?"

Comment: i still want to keep the click event, but i dont want it to start when i try to drag

Comment: I've tried everything and now I ended up with setting a short timeout, where I set a `var dragged` as false and check that one in the click event

Answer (score 0):

You could set a flag variable when the drag starts (`ondragstart`), then when it ends (`ondragend`) you would unset it, and the `onclick` would be wrapped in an `if` condition that would check that flag.

Something like this (you'd need to adjust it to your code):

```
var dragndrop = false;

$(".drag").on("dragstart", function(e) {
    dragndrop = true;
    // ...code here if needed...
});

$(".drag").on("dragend", function(e) {
    dragndrop = false;
    e.preventDefault();
    // ...code here if needed...
});

$("th").on("click", function() {
    if (!dragndrop) {
        // ... your code here 
    }
});
```

Comment: i'm working with the _mousedown_ and _mouseup_ events. sadly the _click_ events starts after the _mouseup_ and the dragndrop variable is set to false :(

Comment: Have you tried keeping your code in the `mousedown` and `mouseup` but adding the `dragstart` and `dragend` just to set/unset the dragndrop flag?