# Problem To Stop Click Event Function On Mousedown Event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the code below, to handle two different events. A **normal left click** & **holding down left click** :

- When users do a normal click, the number add up to one.
- When users hold down the left click, the number will adding up while user holding down the mouse and it stops on mouse up.

Also in both events, I send the result number by AJAX and save it on database.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Normal Click Event
    $('.counter').click(function() {
        var GetNumber = parseInt($(this).text());
        $(this).text(GetNumber + 1);
        
        console.log('Left Click Done!');
        
        // AJAX
        // ...
    });
    
    
    // Hold Click Event
    var ClickStatus = false;
    
    $('.counter').mousedown(function(){
        var Element = $(this);
        var GetNumber = parseInt(Element.text());
        ClickStatus = true;
        
        window.TimeOut = setInterval(function(){
            Element.text(GetNumber++);
        }, 300);

        return false;
    });
    $('.counter').on('mouseup mouseout',function(){
        if (ClickStatus){
            clearInterval(window.TimeOut);
            
            console.log('Hold Left Click Done!');
            
            // AJAX
            // ...
            
            ClickStatus = false;
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

```css
    .counter {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: #1000ff;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 0;
        text-align: center;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-size: 24px;
    }
    .counter:hover {
        opacity: 0.7;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    p {
        font-family: tahoma;
        font-size: 12px;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="counter" title="Left Click / Hold Left Click">1</button>
<p>Click On Above Button, Or Hold Left Click To See The Result.</p>
```

The problem is that both events are firing together! I don't want it, I need to trigger just one of them at time, which means I need to run the events separately.

Also I have tried some solutions like `return false`, `e.stopPropagation()`, `e.stopImmediatePropagation()`, `e.preventDefault()` & ..., read the same topics on the forum:

- [Cancel click event in the mouseup event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8643739/cancel-click-event-in-the-mouseup-event-handler)
- [Jquery mousedown/mouseup prevent click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056647/jquery-mousedown-mouseup-prevent-click)

but unfortunately none of them worked for me and I couldn't find something helpful about it. I'm so confused and have no idea.

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: I think if you remove the onclick function, and keep the onmousedown and onmouseup function, it should give you the same result as onclick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a separate click function, you can manage it with mousedown and mouseup.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Click Event
  let ClickStatus = false;
  let interval, element

  $('.counter').mousedown(function() {
    ClickStatus = true;
    element = $(this)
    increment(element)
    interval = setInterval(function() {
      increment(element)
    }, 300);
  }).on('mouseup mouseout', function() {
    if (ClickStatus) {
      clearInterval(interval);

      console.log('Hold Left Click Done!');

      // AJAX
      // ...

      ClickStatus = false;
    } 
  });
});

function increment(el) {
  el.text(Number(el.text())+1);
}
```

```css
.counter {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #1000ff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.counter:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
  cursor: pointer;
}

p {
  font-family: tahoma;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="counter" title="Left Click / Hold Left Click">1</button>
<p>Click On Above Button, Or Hold Left Click To See The Result.</p>
```

Comment: Thankssss, I thought I need to separate them. But Yes, you're right. So many thanks <3